# CollapsingToolbarLayout: Fix custom layout on top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

here's what I wanna do: I want to display a map in a CollapsingToolbarLayout, below the map should be a custom layout that contains a couple of controls. Below that is a RecyclerView. I want to be able scroll the custom layout as well as the RecyclerView but fix the custom layout at the top while the RecyclerView keeps scrolling. 
Here's an image of what I want to achieve (grey = map; red = custom layout; green = RecyclerView): 
[image]

Here's what I have so far. It works well, except for that the custom layout (red) won't stop scrolling if it reaches the screen's top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                mapbox:zoom="12"
                mapbox:style_url="@string/style_light"
                mapbox:access_token="@string/access_token">
            </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/current_activity"></include>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/activity_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually pretty simple. I just had to move my custom layout into the AppBarLayout.

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                mapbox:zoom="12"
                mapbox:style_url="@string/style_light"
                mapbox:access_token="@string/access_token">
            </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/current_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/activity_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add app:layout_collapseMode="pin"  this attribute in your red view to pin at the top of the screen.
This may fix your issue